# Netty issues with ByteBuf Encoding/Decoding

Tags: java, netty

I'm running into an issue I think I can't solve without some help.
I've setup a simple Client/Server model with Netty. I'm using the 'SimpleChannelInboundHandler' implementation.
When I'm trying to encode an integer and try to decode it on the server side it translates to some random numbers, most often to 0. Before anyone is asking I'm checking for empty buffers.
Does anyone have a clue what could be the problem here?

`Netty-Version 4.1.90-Final JDK/JRE 8 Ubuntu 22.04/Windows 10 (issues are the same on both platforms)`

I've tried to debug this a bit with random integers but it does not work as expected.

Thanks for any hint.

Comment: Can you share code for sending and for receiving?